# Series convergence with log and exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I'm actually having real hard time with this problem....
I tried Ratio test on ii) but r became 1 which means you can't use it(or I solved it wrong...)....

Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ an defined by the following formulas coverge or diverge.

i) $a_1$=$1\over2$, $a_{n+1}=(a_n)^{n+1}$

ii) $a_1$=$1\over2$, $a_{n+1} $=${n+\ln n}\over {n+10}$ $a_n$

Someone save me!

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

I. Notice that for $n\ge 1$, if $0\le a_n\le 1$, then $0\le(a_n)^{n+1}\le a_n$. It should be possible from there to show $a_n$ is positive and monotonic decreasing. The ratio test can be applied from there, since we know that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=(a_n)^n$.

II. For sufficiently large $n$, the ratio $\frac{n+\ln(n)}{n+10}$ will be larger than one. This means that for large $n$, $a_{n+1}>a_n$ provided the terms are positive. Consider what this means for the series.

Comment: humm  I think I got (I), and for (II) should I say that it is till 1 to $3^{10}$ or sort like that and $3^{10}$ to $\infty$?

Comment: At some point ($n=3^{10}$ will suffice) the terms stop getting smaller. If the value of $a_n$ is still positive at that point (which you should show), then the terms certainly won't approach zero, since each is larger than the last.

Comment: Thank you for your help!